# Which certificate does kubelet use?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

This is a kubeadm based 1.16 cluster. The way I understand mTLS work between an apiserver & kubelet is:

apiserver -> kubelet

```
--kubelet-client-certificate & --kubelet-client-key => The certs & key given here(apiserver) is for apiserver(client) to kubelet (server)
--client-ca => The CA given here(kubelet) is what verfies if request from apiserver is indeed the right one.
```

And then we have the other way:

kubelet -> apiserver

```
--tls-cert-file & --tls-key-file => Passed in kubelet conf. Generally present at /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.{crt,key}
--kubelet-certificate-authority => The above cert gets verified by this CA passed in apiserver
```

However, there is a `kubelet.conf` file present at /etc/kubernetes which again has `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` . When is this client-cert used?

Also, if we enable auto-rotation in kubelet, there is a client-cert under `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` which may or may not be referenced in kubelet.conf based on the kubeadm version used (because of the [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1753) in kubeadm prior to 1.17). I'm confused on how & when are the kubelet client cert used. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` are there due to a [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1753). This is well reflected by the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/):

> **Warning:** On nodes created with `kubeadm init`, prior to kubeadm version 1.17, there is a bug where you manually have to modify the
> contents of `kubelet.conf`. After `kubeadm init` finishes, you should
> update `kubelet.conf` to point to the rotated kubelet client
> certificates, by replacing `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data`
> with:
>
> ```
> client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
> client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
> ```

Some useful sources with more info:

- [PKI certificates and requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/)
- [Certificate Management with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/)

**EDIT:**

Based on the [kubelet integration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#workflow-when-using-kubeadm-join):

> When you run `kubeadm join`, kubeadm uses the Bootstrap Token credential
> to perform a TLS bootstrap, which fetches the credential needed to
> download the kubelet-config-1.X ConfigMap and writes it to
> `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`. The dynamic environment file is
> generated in exactly the same way as `kubeadm init`.
>
> Next, `kubeadm` runs the following two commands to load the new
> configuration into the kubelet:
>
> ```
> systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet
> ```
>
> After the kubelet loads the new configuration, kubeadm writes the
> `/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf` KubeConfig file, which contains
> a CA certificate and Bootstrap Token. These are used by the kubelet to
> perform the TLS Bootstrap and obtain a unique credential, which is
> stored in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`. When this file is written, the
> kubelet has finished performing the TLS Bootstrap.

This indicates that cert/credentials stored in `kubelet.conf` are used during kubelet startup process. Removing this file or changing its content will be verified during kubelet restart. This can be tested yourself as below:

- If you remove the file:

---

```
failed to run kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig
```

---

- If you misconfigure the file or provide wrong certs:

---

```
config loaded from file: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/conf
bootstrap.go:240 unable to read existing bootstrap client config: f.e. invalid configuration
or unable to load TLS certificates from existing bootstrap client config: data does not contain any valid RSA or ECDSA certificate
```

---

Also, as a side note:

I strongly recommend using a newer version of Kubernetes as yours is 5 major versions older than the current stable one: 1.21 / April 8, 2021. Keeping things up-to-date will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: Yes, I read about the bug. Have updated my question with the info as well. But when both the embedded certs & certs under /var/lib/kubelet/pki are present, am I right to understand that kubelet actually uses the client certs under pki folder for all the mtls communication & ignores the embedded certs in kubelet.conf ?

Comment: Hi @swetad90. Thanks for your response. I have dug a bit deeper and edited my initial answer to better address your question. Feel free to review it.

Comment: Apologies just seeing this. agree to the use of the kubelet.conf file. Were you able to find anything on the use of the client certs under /var/lib/kubelet/pki directory? Because if I delete those, kubelet fails to restart.

Comment: kubelet is run with command line option `--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`
In the config file, it sets:

`client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem`
`client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem`

So it points to the client cert/key under /var/lib/kubelet/pki.

The cert/key is used for kubelet to talk to apiserver.